# How hashset checks for duplicate elements?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, hashset

Kindly look into my code :

```
HashSet<A> set = new HashSet<A>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    set.add(new A());
System.out.println(set.contains(new A()));
```

Class A is defined as :

```
class A {
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return true;
    }    
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (Math.random()%100);
    }
}
```

If hashset uses hashmap inside......why is the output true ?
Because different hashcodes means their bucket location is different .
So how checking for new A() returns true .

Also if I return 1 always from hashcode output is true which seems ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is your hashcode function:

```
(int) (Math.random()%100);
```

always returns `0`.  So all `A` elements always have the same hashcode.  Therefore all  A elements will be in the same bucket in the HashSet so since your equals will always return true.  As soon as it finds an A in the same bucket (in this case always) it will return true that that A is alreay contained.

`Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1 so that modulo anything will always be`0`.

you probably meant do to `*` instead of `%` to get random numbers between 0 and 100

```
 (int) (Math.random() * 100);
```

Does what you want

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` uses `equals()` on all objects with the same hash bucket to determine `contains()`. Because `equals()` is always `true`, it doesn't matter which bucket the new `A` matches, but all objects will be in the same bucket because `(int)(Math.random() % 100)` is always `0`.

Try changing your hash to:

```
(int)(Math.random() * 100)
```

Comment: hashcode() should be called first to find which bucket to look in first.  THEN equals is called on the elements in that bucket

Comment: @dkatzel of course - that's how it knows what bucket it matches.